# C++ Unhandled exception: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal

Tags: c++

I'm doing a group project at school, we're creating a 2d game, and I'm getting an exception I have no idea what to do with.

A side note: all of this is done in debug mode.

We have a physicsengine class that calculates collision and adds vector forces to entities, the code:

```
void PhysicsEngine::doPhysicsTick()
{
    vector<vector<unordered_set<Entity*>>> *grid = this->grid.getGrid();
    unordered_set<Entity*>* updatable = new unordered_set<Entity*>();
    unordered_set<Entity*>* collidable = new unordered_set<Entity*>();

    const int &r = CollisionGrid::C_GRID_RADIUS;

    for (int row = 0; row < grid->size(); row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < grid->at(row).size(); col++)
    {
        collidable->clear();

        // put all surrounding grid blocks in a entity list to
        // check against collision with the current block

        int rw(row - r > 0 ? row - r : 0);
        int cl(col - r > 0 ? col - r : 0);

        for (int rrow = rw; rrow <= row + r && rrow < grid->size(); rrow++)
        for (int rcol = cl; rcol <= col + r && rcol < grid->at(rrow).size(); rcol++)
            for (Entity *e : grid->at(rrow).at(rcol)) // It crashes here
                collidable->insert(e);

        for (Entity *e : grid->at(row).at(col))
        {
            if (e->isFixed())
                continue;

            e->speed += gravity;

            eBounds.reBox(e->location, e->getSize() + e->speed);

            for (Entity *c : *collidable)
                if (isOverlapping(eBounds, Box(c, c->getSize())) && e != c)
                    doCollision(e, c);

            updatable->insert(e);
        }
    }
```

We have a separate collisiongrid class that manages the grid where we store our entities for collision check (so we don't have to check everything with everything)

the collisiongrid and its underlying `vector` are created when the constructor of the physicsengine is called `PhysicsEngine::PhysicsEngine(World *world) : grid(world)`. But for some reason on only the first tick I see the vector grid points to something nonexistant (size being ridiculously large and such) inside of the loop that fills up collidable.

The error it throws is in the title. If I put a catch block around it, it'll just crash someplace else in some c++ library kind of randomly (different file every time)

and for some reason it crashes in our gameloop class' (the one calling tick of physicsengine) destructor if I don't comment the thing I put in there.

```
Gameloop::~Gameloop()
{
    //if( t ) // t = #include <thread>
    //  delete t;
}
```

We are not allowed to use any libraries outside of the Win32 API and some default c++ libraries

---

Edit: I added some pictures (and undid the dynamic allocation of the unordered_sets)

what it should show:

[image: correct grid]

what it sometimes shows on the first tick:
(notice how the pointers are the same, first two shot where made during the same run)

[image]

what it shows other times on the first tick:

[image]

Comment: is there any reason you are allocating the STL containers dynamically?

Comment: @DavidHaim I was hoping to save some space on the stack, although I'm not even sure it does that (our teacher didn't exactly gave us much information on the topic)

Comment: You don't save that much, because most containers (`std::array` being an exception) have their content dynamically allocated anyway. The container classes themselves are rarely more than a couple of pointers. The content isn't on the stack.

Comment: Check your indices. They are almost certainly out-of-bounds.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit but why? they shouldn't be with all the `i < grid->size()` I'm doing

Comment: In the destructor's comment you mention `thread`. Is this multithreaded? If so the problem could come from race conditions when accessing the grid

Comment: Yes it is multithreaded, but thread access should not be an issue as far as my knowledge goes, the collisiongrid doesn't do anything on its own and is a private member of physicsengine and not used anywhere else. and the thread isn't run until after construction of gameloop, which constructs the physicsengine in its constructor

Comment: How (and when) are you initializing the grid object, the one that calls getGrid()? Is it guaranteed to have been initialized at this point?

Try inserting breakpoints in the grid constructor and in this simulation tick and make sure it is always initialized before running the simulation tick.

Comment: @WhiteNightFury: _"they shouldn't be"_ Yes but _prove it_. Crucial in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your program handle tasks? Because [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/10/26/how-to-debug-a-task-exception-in-windows-store-application.aspx) may solve your problem in that case (those kind of exceptions never crash the program at the right time!)

If not, then you need to debug the program some more. Like printing `rrow`, `rrcol`, `grid->size()`, `grid->at(rrow)->size` everytime before the line where it crashes.

But my money is on the concurrency / memory management side of the code. The fact that it crashes in the destructor in the delete part, makes me think maybe you are handling items that were already deleted elsewhere or concurrently handling items without the appropriate measures. And in your screenshot you have a bunch of `size=???` which maybe means that your item/instance was deleted and your pointer points to free memory, causing the crash when accessing it in your loop. It's a tough error to solve.

Additionnally, you should be able to access parameters of your exception in the debugger, if you can, maybe you can post all of its contents?

Comment: I might not've been very clear on this but, if I uncomment the delete in the destructor and just let it run, the error pops up but it doesn't actually break the program (which happily just goes on with iterating and ticking) which is why I specifically said that it only happens on the first tick. and everything that happens after that first erroring tick is normal expected behaviour. Sorry for the unindented for loops, when I look at a row column double for I just see a single loop and it's more readable this way for me.

Comment: apparently your money was right because I did a `Gameloop g(world)` somewhere and it just went and died, still doesn't explain why it kept on going, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @WhiteNightFury if it can help, I had a similar problem in Xbox programming where I had to make sure absolutely all calls to async APIs had to have a `create_task(call_ret_value).then(...)` with a try / catch for any exception thrown. Anyhow the `disassembleMe` parameter of the exception should point to the problem, as in the link in my answer.