# An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal

Tags: c++

I hope you can help me. I've got this function that I use to save bitmap images but I'm having trouble with the file name. I would like to save the image with the current date on the file name but how I'm currently doing it it's giving me the "An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal" error and the program crashes.

Here is the function that gets the name from the main program:

```
void DoSave(char *Name)
{
    time_t rawTime;
    struct tm *timeInfo;
    char buffer[100];
    string date;

    time(&rawTime);
    timeInfo = localtime(&rawTime);

    strftime(buffer, 100, " %c", timeInfo);
    date = buffer;

    string url("Images/");
    string name(Name);
    string extension(".bmp");

    string path = url + name + date + extension;

    // Open the file for writing
    FILE *f = fopen((const char*)&path, "wb");

    // Save the image as bmp file
    BmpHelper::SaveTo8bppBmpFile(f, (LONG)m_ImageSizeX, (LONG)m_ImageSizeY, (unsigned char*)videoImage);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Here is the function that saves the bitmaps

```
void BmpHelper::SaveTo8bppBmpFile(FILE *output, LONG width, LONG height, unsigned char *buffer)
{
    f8bppHeader_.bfSize = (DWORD)(s8bppHeader_ + width * height);

    i8bppHeader_.biWidth = (LONG)width;
    i8bppHeader_.biHeight = -(LONG)height;

    fwrite(&f8bppHeader_, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, output);
    fwrite(&i8bppHeader_, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, output); // I get the error in this line
    fwrite(p8bpp, sizeof(RGBQUAD), 256, output);
    fwrite(buffer, width, height, output);
}
```

Not sure you need this bit but I'll add it as well.

```
void BmpHelper::Init8bppHeaders()
{
    f8bppHeader_.bfType = 'MB'; // Will be inverted during the fwrite
    s8bppHeader_ = (DWORD)(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD));
    f8bppHeader_.bfReserved1 = 0;
    f8bppHeader_.bfReserved2 = 0;
    f8bppHeader_.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD);

    i8bppHeader_.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    i8bppHeader_.biPlanes = 1;
    i8bppHeader_.biBitCount = 8;
    i8bppHeader_.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    i8bppHeader_.biSizeImage = 0;
    i8bppHeader_.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    i8bppHeader_.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    i8bppHeader_.biClrUsed = 0;
    i8bppHeader_.biClrImportant = 0;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < 256; ++index)
    {
        p8bpp[index].rgbBlue = (BYTE)index;
        p8bpp[index].rgbGreen = (BYTE)index;
        p8bpp[index].rgbRed = (BYTE)index;
        p8bpp[index].rgbReserved = 0;
    }
}
```

If I remove the date from the path it works all right but it only saves the file with the url + name given and file format. I need the date to differentiate between files. Can you guys spot anything wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(const char*)&path` --> `path.c_str()`

Comment: That error message is a runtime error (or exception) that usually results from some form of undefined behaviour in your code.   The problem is that the code which causes the problem may not be related to the line of code where the error occurs  (e.g.  some code misuses a pointer, some later code crashes).    So, since you haven't provided a [mcve], the chances of getting useful help are minimal.   You might want to also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412110/c-unhandled-exception-an-invalid-parameter-was-passed-to-a-function-that-cons

Comment: Tried that @molbdnilo, but it still doesn't work unfortunately. So the code looks OK right? Isn't it weird that if I remove the date part from the filename that it works though @Peter? I'll have a look at the link, thanks!

Comment: Which function causes this runtime error? What are the values of paramters you pass into that function? You need to check results of `fopen` `fwrite` and other c functions. I suspect that file is not getting opened because path is invalid either way.

Comment: Hi @VTT, it happens in the SaveTo8bppBmpFile function in this line:

`fwrite(&i8bppHeader_, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, output);`

This is what I'm passing to it:

`SaveTo8bppBmpFile(f, (LONG)m_ImageSizeX, (LONG)m_ImageSizeY, (unsigned char*)videoImage);`

Stepping though the program it seems the file opens but when I get to that function it breaks.

Comment: Your date string contains characters that are invalid in a path.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to make it a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code is missing many declarations, and it includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date/time string includes `:` characters. Windows file names do not accept any of of these characters `\/:*?"<>|`. You have to replace `:` with a different character.

Also your code does not account for bitmap padding. It works only if bitmap width in bytes is a multiple of 4. Use the following formula to calculate `size` (instead of `width * height`):

```
int size = ((width * bpp + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;
```

`s8bppHeader_ = (DWORD)...` is a typo! `bfSize` is not calculated properly.

You can use C++ functions `std::fstream` instead of mixing C++ and C

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>

...
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
char date[100];
std::strftime(date, sizeof(date), " %c", std::localtime(&t));
for(size_t i = 0, len = strlen(date); i < len; i++)
    if(date[i] == ':')
        date[i] = ','; //use a different character

char *Name = "_abc";
string url("c:\\test\\");
string name(Name);
string extension(".bmp");
string path = url + name + date + extension;

int width = i8bppHeader_.biWidth;
int height = i8bppHeader_.biHeight;
int bpp = i8bppHeader_.biBitCount;

int size = ((width * bpp + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

f8bppHeader_.bfType = 'MB'; // Will be inverted during the fwrite
f8bppHeader_.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
    + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + size;
f8bppHeader_.bfReserved1 = 0;
f8bppHeader_.bfReserved2 = 0;
f8bppHeader_.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
    + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD);

ofstream fout(path, ios::binary);
fout.write((char*)&f8bppHeader_, sizeof(f8bppHeader_));
fout.write((char*)&i8bppHeader_, sizeof(i8bppHeader_));
fout.write((char*)p8bpp, 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD));
fout.write((char*)buffer, size);
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmak Shemirani. Thanks to you I was able to get it to work using the ofstream instead of FILE. For some reason using FILE didn't like me using date even if I used a format that didn't have forbidden characters. Weird...But again, thanks a lot! Not sure I would've gotten it working anytime soon without your answer! Cheers! :D

Comment: Sorry @Barmak Shemirani, only saw this now and it's done.