# How to read a file and print it in c

Tags: c, doc

I'm trying to read the file I attached along with the location of my program (Source) but an exception is thrown at me and I can't understand why
my file has a lot of words with no special characters,
Would appreciate help.

```
    FILE* f;
    char c;
    f = fopen("dictionary.txt", "rt");

    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    fclose(f);
```

**exception her while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {**

The message of debugging is

Expression: stream.void()
for information on how program can cause an assertion failure, see the c++ documentation on asserts.

Comment: I expect the file wasn't opened correctly. You don't check if the file pointer is valid before using it.

Comment: Aside: `char c;` should be `int c;` so that you can distinguish `0xFF` from `EOF`. Most library functions take or return a "character" as `int` not `char`, and in fact e.g. `'A'` is of type `int`. You can use `printf("%c", c)` or `printf("%d", c)` (for character or its encoding) because a `char` passed to `%c` would be promoted to `int` anyway (to a variadic function). It's a beginner mistake to think that "character" is `char`, or that "number" is `int`.

Comment: The error message suggests you are using C++ rather than C.

Comment: how I can solve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value `fopen()` whether a file is opened successfully or not
Note you need to include stdlib.h for using `exit()`

```
    FILE* f;
    int c;
    if ((f = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("error in opening a file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);//printing to the console
    }

    fclose(f);
```

Comment: the message is" error in opening a file" where is the problem?

Comment: Have you check the file exists manually and make sure  passing correct name of the file to the fopen()

Comment: Yes I checked the file I found the driver.c file

Comment: This text file (dictionary.txt) does exists in your current directory or folder? @yovelde

Comment: He was only in the library and then I copied it to a source folder and he now did not record that no file of these made an exception again
"Unhandled exception at 0x79B3FC66 (ucrtbased.dll) in workhome4.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
"

Comment: @yovelde please check with this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412110/c-unhandled-exception-an-invalid-parameter-was-passed-to-a-function-that-cons